# how to sort a lot of data in c?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

at the moment i am trying to write a unreal amount of data out to files,

basically i generate a new struct of data and write it out to file untill the file becomes 1gb big and this occurs for 6 files of 1gb each, the structs are small. 8 bytes long with two 2 variables id and amount

when i generate my data, the structs are created and written to file in the order of amount.
but i need the data to sorted by id.

remember there is 6gb's of data , how could i sort these structs by there id value and then written to file?

or should i write to file first, and then sort each individual file ,and how would i bring all this data together into one file?

i am kind of stuck , because i would like to hold it in an array , but obviously this amount of data is too big.

i need a good way to sort alot of data? (6gb)

Comment: Your keyword is "external sort"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm

Comment: What an odd homework assignment. Is this an imposed requirement or a design issue faced from the current implementation?

Comment: @pst, how is this an odd assignment?  Seems to me like a perfect assignment for an algorithms or database class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found a question with a really basic answer on this, so here goes.

If you're on a 64 bit machine, by the way, you should seriously consider writing all the data into a file, memory mapping the file, and just use whatever array sort you like. Quicksort is pretty cache-friendly: it won't thrash badly. The assignment is probably designed to stop you doing this, but might be a bit out of date ;-)

Failing that, you need some kind of external sort. There are other ways to do it, but I think merge sort is probably the simplest. Before you start merging:

- work out how much data you can fit into memory (or, again, mmap it). If you're on a PC then 1GB seems like a fair assumption, but it may be a few times more or less.
- load this much data (so one of your 6 files, in the example)
- quicksort it (since you tagged "quicksort", I guess you know how to do that), or any other sort of your choice.
- write it back to disk (if you didn't mmap).

This leaves you with 6 1GB files, each of which individually is sorted. At this point you can either work up gradually, or go for the whole lot in one go. With 6 chunks, going for the whole lot is fine, in what is called a "6-way merge":

- open a file for writing
- open your 6 files for reading, and read a few million records out of each
- examine the 6 records at the start of each of the 6 buffers. One of theses 6 must be the smallest of all. Write this to the output, and move forward one step through that buffer.
- as you reach the end of each buffer, refill it from the correct file.

There's some optimization you can do regarding how you work out which of your 6 possibilities is the smallest, but the big performance difference will be to make sure you use large enough read and write buffers.

Obviously there's nothing special about the merge being 6-way. If you'd rather stick to a 2-way merge, which is easier to code, then of course you can. It will take 5 2-way merges to merge 6 files.

Comment: so for the initial stage of sorting the individual files, how would i implement a qsort on the 1gb of data? im not an advanced c programmer and finding it difficult to understand how i would use mmap to allow me to sort the file, if i read in 1gb of data will that not take up the 1gb of space of my memory

Comment: @molleman: unless the assignment says that you have to write your own quicksort, don't: use the `qsort` library function. `mmap` doesn't load the whole file into memory, it just creates a correspondence between virtual addresses, and the physical file. So for a 6GB file you need a 64 bit machine (to have enough address space), but it needn't use 6GB of RAM. I'm a bit surprised, btw, that you've been given this assignment, without first getting an easier one sorting an amount of data that fits in RAM.

Comment: the assingment is a cryptography assignment , and i have store alot of encoded data, and then compare decoded values agianst the stored encoded values, can be stresfull!!

Comment: There's an example in the documentation: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html. You'll need to add the PROT_WRITE flag.

Comment: @molleman: mmap looks scarier than it is, but it is *nix specific.  Windows has a similar function (for this use of mmap) called CreateFileMapping.  mmap might actually slow things down, though, because the OS may decide to sync up the memory and disk data more often than is actually needed unless you map it private, which will then require that you write it back out at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend this tool, it is a light weight database that runs in memory and takes up very little memory. It will hold your information and you can query it to retrieve your information.

http://www.sqlite.org/features.html

Comment: how would i implement this to sort my data?

Comment: @molleman You can use the ORDER BY clause in your SELECT statements like is SQL queries.

Comment: A database is probably overkill (with overhead) if you intend to perform only this one operation and throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't.

If you are to hold such amount of data, why not using a dedicated database format that can have lots of different indexes and a powerful request engine.

But if you still want to use your old fashioned fixed-endian struct, then i would suggest breaking your data into smaller files, sort each one, and merge them. A good merge algorithm runs in nlog(q). Be also sure to pick the right algorithm for your files.

Comment: technically the merge algorithm only takes O(n) time.

Comment: I said n log(q), not n log(n). q is the number of queues.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in development time) to do this is to write out the data to separate files according to their ID.  You don't have to have a 1 to 1 match between the number of files and the number of IDs (in case there are a lot of IDs), but if you choose a prefix of the ID (so if the key for one particular record is 987 it might go in the 9 file while the record with key 456 would go in the 4 file) you won't have to worry about locating all of the keys across all of the files because sorting each file by itself would result and then looking at the files in their order (by their names) would give you sorted results.

If that is not possible or easy the you need to do an external sort of some type.  Since the data is still spread across several files this is a bit of a pain.  The easiest thing (by development time) is to first sort each individual file independently and then merge them together into a new set of files sorted by ID.  Look up *merge*  *sort* if you don't know what I'm talking about.  At this step you are pretty much starting in the middle of merge sort.

As far as sorting the contents of a file which is too large to fit into RAM you can either use merge sort directly on the file or use *replacement*  *selection*  *sort* to sort the file in place.  This involves making several passes over the file while using some RAM (the more the better) to hold a priority queue (a binary heap) and a set of records that are not possibly of any use in this run (their keys suggest that they should be earlier in the file than the current run position, so you're just holding on to them until the next run).

Searching for *replacement*  *selection*  *sort* or *tournament*  *sort* will yield better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

First, sort each file individually. Either load the whole thing into memory, or (better) `mmap` it, and use the `qsort` function.

Then, write your own merge sort that takes `N` `FILE *` inputs (i.e. `N=6` in your case) and outputs to `N` new files, switching to the next one whenever one fills up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). Find any of the external mergesort libraries out there and modify them to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Well - since the actual assignment is to keep encoded data and later just compare it with decoded-data, I would also say - use a database and just create an hash index on the ID column.

But regarding sort of such hugh number, another very important thing is to do it in parallel. There are many ways to do it. Steve Jessop mentioned a sort-merge approach, it is really easy to sort the first 6 chunks in parallel, the only question is how much cpu cores andd memory you have on your machine. (It is rare to find a computer with only 1 core today and also not so rare to have 4GB memory).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use mmap and use it as a huge array which you could sort with qsort. I'm not sure what the implications would be. Would it grow to much in memory?